# Shorter notation for sine function

Tags: trigonometry, notation

TL;DR: Are there shorter, established notations for the sine function and other trigonometric functions than "$ \sin(x) $" etc.?

In a some homeworks and tests, there are exercises (e.g. differential equations or matrices) which contains sine and cosine, which I have to write very often - obviously, this becomes quite annoying.

My usual "workaround" is, that I define $ \sin(x) = s $ and $ \cos(x) = c $ to safe me from writing the rest and loose time unessecarily. As far as I can see, this is totally correct and can't be marked as wrong.

Yet this reduces the readability (and probably annoys the corrector). So are there any shorter notations for the trigonometric functions, which are  established or at least sometimes used?

Comment: When there is no confusion with other variables, parameters or constants, then your notation seems to be quite ok. And I've also seen this in the context of complex analysis, for example the cis-function. Shorter than one letter isn't possible.

Comment: There is unlikely to be any alternative, widely used notation since $1$ possibly confusing symbol is realistically not much of an improvement on $4$ or $6$ recognizable symbols. If you want to speed up your algebra, you're perfectly entitled to define $s$ as $\sin x$ or even $z=\sin x + \cos x + \ldots$ as long as you're clear. Doing so is very common.

Comment: I have seen $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ used in kinematics calculations where rotation matrices are chained together. But frankly, you are free to use any notation as long as you define it.

Comment: In my own (unpublished) work in hyperbolic geometry, I use "$
\ddot{\theta}$" and "$\ddot{x}$" for "$\cos\theta$" and "$\cosh x$", and "$\overline{\theta}$" and "$\overline{x}$" for "$\sin\theta$" and "$\sinh x$". (I also use subscripts for some fractions; eg, "$\ddot{\theta_2}$" for "$\cos(\theta/2)$".) Thus, a hyperbolic Laws of Cosines compacts as $$\cosh c=\cosh a\cosh b-\sinh a\sinh b\cos\gamma\quad\to\quad\ddot{c}=\ddot{a}\ddot{b}-\overline{a}\overline{b}\ddot{\gamma}$$ My work avoids the complex plane, so no confusion with conjugation. All in all, the notation works nicely for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no such other notation. Your relabelling approach is certainly fine (except maybe if the work is being marked by someone unwilling to look through your custom symbol definitions). But I'd concentrate on whether your proofs are more verbose than necessary for other reasons. Writing in terms of $e^{ix}$ would shorten many proofs, especially if it's appropriate in that context to write e.g. $z=e^{ix}$.

In contexts where multiple angles are indexed viz. $\theta_i$, it's common to use notation such as $c_i:=\cos\theta_i$ etc. See e.g. the tabulated results in terms of proper Euler angles & Tait–Bryan angles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix). Credit goes to @JohnDouma for this observation.

Comment: His notation is standard in robotics texts.

Comment: @JohnDouma If you know of a source doing that to which you can link, it would be worth discussing it in an answer.

Comment: Pick any textbook that covers Euler angles. As more matrices are multiplied together the notation becomes cumbersome so you see this notation. Google "robotics sin notation" and look at any of the lecture notes or texts that come up. You will see sin and cos but when you get to Euler angles and see compositions the notation is common.

Comment: @JohnDouma That search string didn't help as much as I hoped, but I've made an edit that addresses what appears to have been your point regarding Euler angles. If robotics also uses these abbreviations for unindexed angles, so that my answer leaves such an example unaddressed, please consider writing an answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would from my experience assume that there is nothing shorter for the sine or the cosine etc other than the usual ones. Think of the following, sin is a three-letter word the best we could shorten it to is one or two-letter word, now naming sin as si and cosine as co would just create a headache to anyone correcting (to me at least it would) and what is the benefit? Even if it was 100 letters saved I assure you it is not worth it.

P.S I think such a question would be more appropriate to a StackExchange more towards the linguistic aspect.

Comment: Your PS should be a comment on the question, not part of an answer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @J.G I am kind of new to the community.